# What plugin did SO use for making the popup alert in the login screen?

Tags: discussion

What plugin did SO use for the login screen alert like in the below image?

Is this a jQuery plugin or Bootstrap tooltip? Or what is this thing called? What I found was a tooltip, but it looks like the alert is not a tooltip...

[image]

Comment: Those are the same message that they use elsewhere on the site.

Comment: @Braiam and what is this thing called ? popups ? tooltip ?

Answer (score 5):

It's a custom rolled solution; you can find the source code in the page JS source. (Psst, if you're not a fan of reading minified code, [there's a dev mirror](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/full.en.js).) You can also call them yourself from the browser console - I once knew how to do this, but it would appear the internal API has changed since then :)

They're not quite tooltips - tooltips tend to appear on mouseover. You could call them popups, but popups tend to be associated with things opening in new browser tabs/windows. I'd call them contextual notifications.

Comment: it's similar with modal but it's not clickable, so maybe it's a combination between modal and popup ?

Comment: I've heard of the term "popover" when similar features exist in other javascript/css libraries.